# Rails Join Table Uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I'm trying to verify the uniqueness of the rows in the join table Employee by user_id & restaurant_id.

Other posts suggest something like this, but it doesn't work with ":id" as attribute, because it still applies duplicates when I test it.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :id, :scope => [:user_id, :restaurant_id]
```

Maybe the shovel assignment `@restaurant.users << @user` does not verify for uniqueness?

Models:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employees
    has_many :users, through: :employees
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :restaurants, through: :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Best work around I could find was to verify within the controller like so:

`if @restaurant.users.include?(@user)`

Which in my case is fine because I only perform that action in one place in my app, but I wonder if there is a better way to make it more DRY in other cases.